# Inluded templates in twig print special characters as ascii in assets

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony-2.7

I have a problem with Symfony 2.7.1

I recently upgraded my project from 2.3 to 2.7.1.

I check all my project searching deprecated things to fix it, but when I open an action twig included templates which in turn contain assets, they are shown with bars directory in ASCII.

I leave an example of the problem, see if someone can give me a solution.

In my template

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% include 'AdminBundle:Global:notifications.html.twig' %}    
    {% include '::genemu.js.html.twig' with {'form': form} %}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the content in genemu.js.html.twig that shows wrongly

```
{% javascripts output='admin/js/compiled/main_forms.js'
    'bundles/bmatznerjqueryui/js/minified/jquery-ui.min.js'
    'bundles/pinanoselect2/js/select2.full.min.js'
    'uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js'
    'tinymce/js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js'
    'datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js'
%}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

It shows like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="\x2Fapp_dev.php\x2Fadmin\x2Fjs\x2Fcompiled\x2Fmain_forms_jquery\x2Dui.min_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\x2Fapp_dev.php\x2Fadmin\x2Fjs\x2Fcompiled\x2Fmain_forms_select2.full.min_2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\x2Fapp_dev.php\x2Fadmin\x2Fjs\x2Fcompiled\x2Fmain_forms_jquery.uploadify.min_3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\x2Fapp_dev.php\x2Fadmin\x2Fjs\x2Fcompiled\x2Fmain_forms_jquery.tinymce.min_4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\x2Fapp_dev.php\x2Fadmin\x2Fjs\x2Fcompiled\x2Fmain_forms_jquery.datetimepicker_5.js"></script>
```

I think must be an issue from 2.7.1 because it works fine in 2.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because newer versions of Twig are detecting your `genemu.js.html.twig` as javascript (Because of the js in it) and now the js escaping strategy is used.

Rename your file to `genemu.html.twig` because it's a html.